How do I add an ACF block to a custom PHP Wordpress template that preloads in the block editor?
I have a custom WP template single-page.php which can be populated with my custom ACF blocks. Initially I created Hero controls using ACF fields to ensure they were always present and could not be removed from the page, but these appear anchored to the foot of the editor and cannot be moved—they are always belows any other ACF blocks that get added to the page.
( The hero section is the first section of the page, and always appears at the top of every page, only once ).
I have moved the Hero controls to an ACF block to streamline the content editing experience and ensure it is following the same pattern os the other code blocks. However, this block can be added/removed to and from the page, and moved up and down the page.
How do I now ensure the block is pre-loaded when the block editor loads?
I have read https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#custom-post-types however I am not registering a custom post type, I am simply writing some code that sets the default "page" template to be my single-page.php file:
if (is_singular('page')) {
  $default_template = locate_template(array('single-page.php'));
  if ('' != $default_template) {
    $template =  __DIR__ . '/single-page.php';
  }
}

I am registering my blocks in functions.php like this:
function register_acf_blocks()
{
    register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/blocks/hero');
}
add_action('init', 'register_acf_blocks');

My ACF blocks each follow this file structure (assume the block name is hero) and all sit inside my /blocks folder:
/hero

block.json
hero.php

When reading from WP, my template simply does the following:
<?php while (have_posts()) {
   the_post(); 
   the_content();
} ?>

I have tried adding the following to /hero/block.json:
"supports": {
    "anchor": true,
    "align": false,
    "lock": false,
    "multiple": false,
    "renaming": false,
    "reusable": false
},
"attributes": {
        "lock": {
          "type": "object",
          "default": {
          "remove": true,
          "move": true
          }
        }
      }

This does half the job — the Hero block must be manually added to a page, after which it cannot be removed or moved, however, other blocks can still be moved above it.

Did you find a solution for this? Im at the exact same "challenge" right now, wanting to preload and lock a hero block on a specific custom template

Not yet—the closest I have got relies on the user doing two things:

Adding the hero block to the page
Not dragging other blocks above it.
I could write a loop to pre-check for the existence of the hero block and render it out first which takes care of the second issue.

